# Getting Full Path of File in Working Directory

Tags: autohotkey

```
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

FileRead, string, file.txt
MsgBox,0,, %string%
```

Because of:

```
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
```

I can reference file.txt without being explicit about its path, but for a project, I need the complete file path, but I'm not sure how to get it. Ideally, I wouldn't like to use FileSelectFile because that will just add another step for the user.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 5):

Use a file loop and `A_LoopFileLongPath`:

```
Loop, Files, file.txt
{
    fullpath := A_LoopFileLongPath    
}
MsgBox, fullpath: %fullpath%
```